# Radio button & checkbox bug

Tags: javascript, php

I have two radio box.
One is called as "Locked" & other as "Unlocked"

Lock & Unlocked Button as following:

```
<label>
<input name="radiogroup_<?php echo $RepeatSelectionCounter_2; ?>" type="radio" value="Y" id="locked" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_MultipleLOPStatus['LOPStatus'],"Y"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> >  Lock
 </label> 

 <label>
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_MultipleLOPStatus['LOPStatus'],"N"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="radiogroup_<?php echo $RepeatSelectionCounter_2; ?>" type="radio" value="N"  id="unlocked">
Unlock
</label>
```

I have checkout box which is like this:

```
<label class="css-input switch switch-success">
<input type="checkbox" name="completed" value="5" id="completed" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_EditJobStatus['Status'],5))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> ><span></span> Choose if you completed your job!
```

Now on clicking checkbox (id=completed) i want 'unlocked'(radio) to be checked & 'locked' (radio) to be unchecked even if it is manually checked.

When i check 'completed' checkbox 'unlock' (radio) does get checked. but 'locked' radio doesn't get unchecked & can be checkable still on 'locked'.

I have following scripts:

```
 <script>
        var completed = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='5']");
var unlocked = $("input[type='radio'][value='N']");

completed.on('change', function(){
    unlocked.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
        </script>

 <script>

 $(document).on("click", "input[id='unlocked']", function(){
    thisRadio = $(this);
    if (thisRadio.hasClass("imChecked")) {
        thisRadio.removeClass("imChecked");
        thisRadio.prop('checked', false);
    } else { 
        thisRadio.prop('checked', true);
        thisRadio.addClass("imChecked");
    };
})

</script>

<script>

 $(document).on("click", "input[id='locked']", function(){
    thisRadio = $(this);
    if (thisRadio.hasClass("imChecked")) {
        thisRadio.removeClass("imChecked");
        thisRadio.prop('checked', false);
    } else { 
        thisRadio.prop('checked', true);
        thisRadio.addClass("imChecked");
    };
})

</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see the code in action

Comment: @DarrenSweeney currently its all using dynamic data.

Comment: So make something up - it's far easier to test/debug when you're using actual code instead of just reading it

Comment: @DarrenSweeney how about screenshot?

Comment: Run your code, copy the rendered html into a fiddle, then add your javascript - it's pretty easy